# Выполнение функции после только после выполнения первой

Tags: javascript

Есть функция `setTimeout(removeLoader,2000);`
только когда она закончит выполнение нужно запустить функцию clear();
как такое сделать?

Comment: В теле ф-ии `removeLoader` допишите `clear()` : )

Comment: мне кажется что такой подход мне не подойдет, так как после removeLoader будет идти много функций еще

Comment: @hil400k Почему метод @sergiks не подходить? Опишите проблему поподробней.